# Generic array In Java

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I am trying to figure out why my code gives an error -

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:

```
The method maximum(T[]) in the type find_max is not applicable for the arguments (int[])
The method maximum(T[]) in the type find_max is not applicable for the arguments (double[])
```

**Code**

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T maximum(T [] a) throws Exception { 
    System.out.println("here"); 
    T max=a[0]; // assume x is initially the largest 
    for (T i : a) { 
        if (i.compareTo(max) > 0) { 
            max=i; 
        } 
    } 
    return max; // System.out.println("Max is " + max); 
}
```

Comment: public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T maximum(T [] a) throws Exception
   {             

      T max=a[0]; // assume x is initially the largest       
   
      for (T i : a)
      {
          if (i.compareTo(max) > 0)
          {
              max=i;
          }
      }
      
      return max;
      
   }

Comment: Can you provide the code snippet and error stack?

Comment: Because `int` and `double` are primitive types and not usable for generic types.

Comment: forgot to put it in there :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For method signatures like this one:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T maximum(T [] a)
```

the `T` type-parameter stands for a *reference type* (and even more - a reference type `T` that is a sub-type of `Comparable<T>`) and later on it's replaced with some specific reference type.

You're invoking the method with `int[]` or `double[]`. In these cases the possible replacements for `T` are `int` or `double`, which are not reference types, but primitive types.

If you did (for example):

```
Integer array = new Integer[] { 1, 2, 3 };
method(array);
```

then the compiler error wouldn't appear, as `Integer` (unlike `int`) is a *reference type* and is a sub-type of `Comparable<Integer>`, which makes it a suitable replacement for `T` at Runtime.

Comment: Thanks ... It was a great help :)